# Wordpress get plugin directory

Tags: wordpress

Is there any function that would return the full path of my plugin in WordPress?

Example is

```
path/wp-contents/plugins/myplugin
```

I have tried `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)` but returns the current dir.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yeah as per description of [plugin_dir_path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path) it will give you current plugin file path. But as per what you asking here you can do something like below unfortunately no direct way,

```
$plugin_dir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/plugin-folder/';
```

*Edit: 18-09-2021*

The best practice is to use with latest version is WP_PLUGIN_DIR as follow:

```
$plugin_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/plugin-folder';
```

Comment: is there a way without manualy specifying plugin-folder? like plugin_url, but returns an absolute path not the url path.

Comment: I guess the only way is what i mention in answer.

Comment: This is not a good example: 'wp-content' can have any name on a WordPress installation, and this code will break in that case.

Comment: Yeah, this is terrible; you should use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` instead.

Comment: I like WP_PLUGIN_DIR personally for this solution. It does make it better.

Comment: Except of WP_PLUGIN_DIR you should also check WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR for must use plugins.

Comment: @slikts per [WordPress' documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories): *These should not be used directly by plugins or themes, but are listed here for completeness.* It then lists a few constants, including `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`.

Answer (score 110):

I would suggest to use a WordPress internal constant to solve this case:

```php
$my_plugin = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my-plugin';

if ( is_dir( $my_plugin ) ) {
    // plugin directory found!
}
```

*Alternative*

The other valid alternative is to compute the path from the URL which is more complex/confusing. I would not use this code:

```php
$plugins_url = plugins_url();
$base_url = get_option( 'siteurl' );
$plugins_dir = str_replace( $base_url, ABSPATH, $plugins_url );
// Now $plugins_dir is same as the WP_PLUGIN_DIR constant.

$my_plugin = $plugins_dir . '/my-plugin';
```

My opinion in this case is: Use the constant `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`

Comment: It's worth mentioning the name `plugin_dir_path` is very misleading – it's not really anything to do with plugins at all, it's just a wrapper for `trailingslashit`, which in turn just runs `dirname()` on whatever value you supply.

Comment: Doesn't work in vagrant, provides the /srv/www/yoursite/ path. Wordpress recommends `plugins_url( 'myscript.js', __FILE__ );`

Comment: @gregbast1994 that's right (and intended). This code does not return the URL but the absolute PATH to the plugin folder.

Answer (score 20):

> Code For Plugin Root Path

```
$dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
```

> ```
> // Example: /home/user/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/
> ```
>
> Code for plugin path

```
echo  WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/plugin-name';
```

Comment: This only provides the plugin directory when it is called from a file that is at the base of the plugin's directory. When you pass `__FILE__` to it, it simply retrieves the directory of the current file.

Answer (score 17):

**`plugins_dir_path()`** is a misnomer.
It will always return the path to the **current** file.

Link to the codex:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/#more-information

> It is a wrapper for trailingslashit( dirname( $file ) );.
>
> The “plugin” part of the name is misleading – it can be used for any file, and will not return the directory of a plugin unless you call it within a file in the plugin’s base directory.

It is actually synonym for the `trailingslashit()` function.

**IF** the current file is in the `plugins` directory, **then** yes, the function returns the path of the current file.
However, if you call this function from a file inside *any other directory*, then current file is *not* in the plugins directory, and thus it will *does NOT* return the path to the plugins directory.  It *does* always return the path to the current file, but without a trailing slash.

Most of the answers here are incorrect, or are only "sometimes" correct.  Those answers will only work as they say IF your file happens to already be located in the plugins directory!  In all other cases they will give you a misleading result: the path to your current file.

---

It is more likely that your file is in a *subdirectory *of the plugins folder.

If this is the case, this codex shows you how to create a URL to the current file:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

> If you are using the plugins_url() function in a file that is nested inside a subdirectory of your plugin directory, you should use PHP's dirname() function:
>
> `<?php
>   echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/wordpress.png', dirname(__FILE__) ) . '" > ';
>   ?>`

You would then need to remove your file name to get the path.
Or use ``

#### ANSWER:

These solutions solutions are independant of where the file of your calling function is located.  If your file is located in the plugins folder, or a subdirectory of it, then the above options would work.  Otherwise, you'll need to resort to something along the lines of:

**`WP_PLUGIN_DIR`**

WordPress *does* have a constant defined, for the Plugins' folder:

Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

> Constants
>
> WordPress makes use of the following constants when determining the path to the content and plugin directories. These should not be used directly by plugins or themes, but are listed here for completeness.
>
> WP_CONTENT_DIR  // no trailing slash, full paths only
>   WP_CONTENT_URL  // full url
>   WP_PLUGIN_DIR  // full path, no trailing slash
>   WP_PLUGIN_URL  // full url, no trailing slash
>
> // Available per default in MS, not set in single site install
>   // Can be used in single site installs (as usual: at your own risk)
>   UPLOADS // (If set, uploads folder, relative to ABSPATH) (for e.g.: /wp-content/uploads)

---

Or, If you can guarantee that the plugins folder is located in the normal place for a WordPress install, [i_a's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398640/5411817) answer above will work, no matter what directory your file (that you want to call this function from) is in. 
Please see his more complete post in this thread, but so as to not have a "link only answer", I'll include here that it Essentially, it boils down to using the following (and turning it into a function):

```
$plugins_root = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins';
```

Or M07's post, also in this thread, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28525164/5411817

Comment: Really great answer. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Kinda late to this party, but just in case some else stumbles upon this.

`plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)` will always return the current path (where the file calling it is located).
If you want the root, use the code below:

```
plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) )
```

You can then define a constant:

```
define( 'YOUR_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
require_once YOUR_PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/admin-page.php'
require_once YOUR_PLUGIN_DIR . 'admin/classes.php'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can define a constant into your main PHP file. It should be at the root of your plugin folder.
The file should be here : `.../wp-content/plugins/plugin-folder/my-plugin.php`

You can add into the file this line.

```
define( 'MYPLUGIN__PLUGIN_DIR_PATH', plugins_url( '', __FILE__ ) );
```

After you can use your new constant anywhere in your plugin.

```
public function Test() 
    {   
            $folder2 = MYPLUGIN__PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . '/folder1/folder2/';
           // $folder2 = .../wp-content/plugins/plugin-folder/folder1/folder2/
    }
```

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Good solution, with plugins_url changed to plugin_dir_path

Answer (score 5):

As noted on the section `Common Usage` of [Plugins Url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) function reference page, that's what worked for me:

> If you are using the plugins_url() function in a file that is nested inside a subdirectory of your plugin directory, you should use PHP's dirname() function:

```
echo plugins_url('', dirname(__FILE__) );
```

The output for this was:

```
http://domain/app/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin
```

The file that called the function was my `functions.php` inside `includes`, so the complete path to my file was:

```
http://domain/app/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/includes/functions.php
```

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest following code. if you are accessing this function from any subfolder.

```
plugins_url( 'images/logo.png' , dirname(__FILE__ ));
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, most of the answers here seem to forget about one important thing.

In addition to the plugins dir, plugins might be also in the [Must-use plugins (mu-plugins) directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)

Because of that, we need to check multiple directories.
An example function to do this:

```
function get_plugin_dir_path($pluginFolderName){

    if ( defined( 'WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR' ) && file_exists( trailingslashit( WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR ) . $pluginFolderName ) ) {
        return trailingslashit( WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR ) . $pluginFolderName;
    } elseif ( defined( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR' ) && file_exists( trailingslashit( WP_PLUGIN_DIR ) . $pluginFolderName ) ) {
        return trailingslashit( WP_PLUGIN_DIR ) . $pluginFolderName;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: I Recommend check the default plugin dir first. It has more chances that the plugin is there, reducing the necessary processing.

Comment: Actually, I did that on purpose. Mu plugins have precedence this same if you will have duplicated plugin (and plugin checks if functions were not defined) the first one will be in use.

Comment: To clarify for future readers, this is only needed on multi-site WordPress installations, correct @MaciejPaprocki ?

Comment: This is needed on installations using must use plugins. https://wpscholar.com/blog/wordpress-must-use-plugins/ . That can be used on mu and non mu.

Comment: Must-use plugins can be found on both multi-site and single-site installations.

Answer (score 3):

`plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` will give you plugin **path of current file**.

this is mean if you call this function like that inside **"your_plugin_dir/sub_dir/file.php"**
will return **"your_plugin_dir/sub_dir/"**

if you want to get the **ROOT of your plugin directory**, just change `__FILE__` to `__DIR__`

```
plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ )
```

Comment: Actually `__DIR__` only moves up a single directory, it doesn't take you to the root directory. `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/include/classes/` would become `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/include/`

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a solution, when you are not inside the plugin root:**

As of now with **4.7.5**, WordPress **does not have** a **get_plugins_root()** function like there is a **get_theme_root()** function. This is probably because you really shouldn't ever need to modify plugins from your theme, and the plugins root directory never changes.

However, it can be useful if you need to programmatically affect plug-ins while developing themes.

Simply, as WP does for the theme root:

```
$plugin_root = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins';
```

Or, if you need a function, why not just do it the same way WordPress does it for the theme root?

Just make a copy of the function **get_theme_root()** from **wp-includes/theme.php** and paste it into your theme's functions.php file, rename the function to get_plugins_root(), simplify it, and change 'theme' to 'plugins' in the function...

```
get_plugins_root() {

    $plugins_root = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins';

    /**
     * Filters the absolute path to the plugins directory.
     *
     * @since now
     *
     * @param string $plugins_root Absolute path to plugins directory.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'plugins_root', $plugins_root );
}
```

With the path, you can now add the plug-ins folder name that you wish to affect.

```
$the_plugin_root = get_plugins_root()."/the-plugin-name/";
```

Comment: WordPress has a constant where you can define the root of your plugins which is even documented in the Codex. [WP_PLUGIN_DIR](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories)

Answer (score 2):

My solution has been to use inside plugin_dir_path **DIR**

```
plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . $path_inside_plugin_folder;
```

The above should give you the absolute path to your plugin folder on the server, then you can load your variable with any file within your plugin folder

Comment: This only provides the plugin directory when it is called from a file that is in a subfolder that is, in turn, located at the base of the plugin's directory. When you pass `__DIR__` to `plugin_dir_path`, it simply retrieves the parent directory of the directory where the current file is located.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, there isn't any function that will return only the full path of your plugin's base directory.

However, the constant `WP_CONTENT_DIR` is used by WordPress for just about that. But, even though, WordPress uses this constant, they warn us not to use it directly in our plugins or themes. That's because it can cause issues like when users change or rename their plugin's directory from the default one.

Using the `plugin_dir_path()` function will return the path of the file's directory from where it is called. So, if you call this function from a PHP file that is inside a subfolder of your plugin, it will return the path of that subfolder's directory and not your plugin's base directory.

## Answer

Now, as a workaround, we can define a constant in a PHP file that is directly inside the plugin's base directory and then set its value to the result of calling `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )`. This way, we will be able to use that constant anywhere in the plugin to get the full path of the plugin's base directory.

So, open a PHP file located directly in your plugin's base directory. For instance:

```
../wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php
```

Then, define a constant by setting its value to the result of calling `plugin_dir_path()` function. For instance:

```
define( 'MYPLUGIN_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
```

This constant now holds the path of your plugin's root directory. So, now, if you echo that constant from any file located in any directory of your plugin like this:

```
echo MYPLUGIN_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH;
```

It will print something like this:

```
/home/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @tsl143 the function [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) is what you want, along with the `__FILE__` magic constant. If you call it from a file inside your plugin folder it will refer to that folder.

Example:

#### For the directory:

```
echo plugins_url( '' , __FILE__ ); 
//outputs: http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin
```

#### For a file or subdirectory in your plugin directory:

```
echo plugins_url( 'images/logo.png' , __FILE__ ); 
//outputs: http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images/logo.png
```

Comment: The OP asked for the path, not the URL

Comment: I actually needed the URL so while it was the wrong answer, you answered my question

Answer (score 0):

You can gain it by using this method

```
plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ )
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions either won't work if called from a sub-directory of your plugin or they require that you to hard code your plugin's directory name or you need to define a global variable.

My solution uses a function that can be placed in any directory of your plugin without requiring that you to hard code something.

```
function get_my_plugin_root_dir()
{
    // WP_PLUGIN_DIR will have something like "/home/michael/public_html/wp-content/plugins"
    // __DIR__ will have something like "/home/michael/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-folder/the-dir-being-called-from
    
    // First, we remove WP's root plugin path from our __DIR__ path.
    $path_to_this_files_dir_without_wp_plugin_dir = str_replace(WP_PLUGIN_DIR, '', __DIR__);

    // Now, we're left with only our plugin's path, which looks like
    // this: "/my-plugin-folder/the-dir-being-called-from"

    // Next, we discard any sub-directories that are included with our
    // plugin's path and keep the first directory in the path, our 
    // plugin's directory name.
    $plugin_directory_name_only = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path_to_this_files_dir_without_wp_plugin_dir)[1];

    // Now $plugin_directory_name_only has "my-plugin-folder"

    // Lastly, we build the plugin's complete root path using 
    // WP's root plugin directory and our plugin's root dir name.
    return WP_PLUGIN_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $plugin_directory_name_only;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution wasn't available when the original answer was accepted.
If the current file is two folders down into the plugin path, use this:

```php
$plugin_path = plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__, 2));
$plugin_url = plugin_dir_url(dirname(__FILE__, 2));
```

Note the number as the second parameter on [dirname()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), available since PHP v7.0.0.

The technique to use a constant works with this too, this time outside of the root-level plugin.php :

```php
// from pluginname/src/API/Common/Constants.php
define( 'MYPLUGIN_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH', plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__, 3)) );
```

Note [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php#54868) on the PHP Manual site:

> Dirname likes to mess with the slashes.

So I normalize the path to avoid double slashes, and slashes that are wrong for the current OS:

```php
$normalized = wp_normalize_path( $plugin_path . '/' . $required_file);
if (file_exists($normalized))
  require_once $normalized;
else
  die(__('Required file does not exist') . ": $normalized");
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, using `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)` works to get the directory of your plugin if used within the main plugin file (e.g. `plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php`.

But what if you want to know the plugin directory from another file in your plugin? Well what I like to do is define a constant in my main plugin file like this;

```
// plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php

define('MYPLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
```

Then in other php files within your plugin, you can use `MYPLUGIN_PATH` (a constant) anywhere you like, without knowing the directory structure!

Answer (score 0):

rather than take the advice of someone who's not using your server (and continue guessing at it...)

why not just load a so-called "Classic" theme, and see what you get?
You're either going to get a relative, or an absolute path. It's not random. figure it out. if you don't like the output, change the function/ args. If you don't know the function names, Install Visual Studio Code, and one of the several WordPress autocomplete / intellisense plugins. It basically writes the code for you.

e.g. ./wp-content/themes/classic/footer.php

```
wp_footer(); 
echo '<br><strong>plugin_dir_url(dirname(__FILE__))</strong><br>&nbsp;'. plugin_dir_url(dirname(__FILE__));
echo '<br><strong>plugins_url()</strong><br>&nbsp;'. plugins_url();
echo '<br><strong>__FILE__</strong><br>&nbsp;' .__FILE__ .'<br>';
?>
```

go from there.