# My function to create a csv file in php goes through but doesnt create the file

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

Hey guys this is my code.

```
        function markenbuero_csv() {

        // open the file "demosaved.csv" for writing
        $file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'w');

        // save the column headers
        fputcsv($file, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));

        // Sample data. This can be fetched from mysql too
        $data = array(
            array('Data 11', 'Data 12', 'Data 13', 'Data 14', 'Data 15'),
            array('Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25'),
            array('Data 31', 'Data 32', 'Data 33', 'Data 34', 'Data 35'),
            array('Data 41', 'Data 42', 'Data 43', 'Data 44', 'Data 45'),
            array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55')
        );

        // save each row of the data
        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
        fputcsv($file, $row);
        }

        // Close the file
        fclose($file);  
        echo 'worked';
    }
```

i call it over a form from my Wordpress custom plugin page and it echos the "worked" but doesnt create the file in my plugin folder.
The Form looks like this:

```
<form style="margin-top:50px" action="#" method="post"> 
<input type="submit" name="a_submit" value="CSV laden">
</form>
```

and the way i call it:

```
if(isset($_POST['a_submit'])){
            markenbuero_csv();
        }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Appreciate if you help me out.

Comment: _“but doesnt create the file in my plugin folder.”_ - that’s probably because you did specify a file name only. This code might be _located_ in your plugin files, but that does not mean that this will also be the _working directory_ of the main script instance that embeds and runs your plugin code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780422/wordpress-get-plugin-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uses the absolute path to ensure the file is in the right place

```
$path = realpath('./your-directory') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'demosaved.csv';
$file = fopen($path, 'w');
```